# Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'Year' not found

Tags: r, object, anova

I'm new to R, so please bear with me! I'm trying to run a simple ANOVA.

I keep getting the following error: "Error in `eval(expr, envir, enclos)` : object `Year` not found."

Here is my code:

```
library (stats)
FISH <- read.table("fish.csv", header=T)

*# One Way Anova (Completely Randomized Design)*

fit <- aov(Year ~ Avg, data=FISH)
```

Comment: Need to see the data. Add the output of `head(FISH)` please.

Comment: If your data is a csv you will likely need to specify `sep=","` or use `read.csv` instead. Have you looked at your data `str(FISH)`

Comment: Voting to close as not reproducible and op non responsive